# Insert image into PostgresSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, image

I was trying to insert into a postgres database.
This is the Query

```
INSERT INTO public.tblcast(
    castname, castimage)
    VALUES ('Henry Cavill',bytea('E:\Cast\henry.jpg'));
```

But it shows an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
LINE 3:  VALUES ('Henry Cavill',bytea('E:\Cast\henry.jpg'));
                                      ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 81ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea
```

The column castimage is with data type bytea.

Comment: can you also share the type of column - `castimage` ?

Comment: `castimage bytea`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: It's been a while since I answered this question, but I guess I got it wrong and although the OP seemed happy with the answer, I believe it needs a few comments. Thanks to Daniel Vérité!

**lo_import**

Using [`lo_import`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/lo-funcs.html) you can import files using absolute paths, but it returns an object of type [`OID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-oid.html), so you'd need to change your column data type - also proposed by stud3nt in another answer.

```
INSERT INTO public.tblcast(castname, castimage)
VALUES ('Henry Cavill',lo_import('server_path_to_file'));
```

If you don't have the luxury of placing the files in the server before import (like the most of us), you can use the `\lo_import` facility with [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html) from your console:

```
echo "\lo_import '/client_path_to_file' \\\ INSERT INTO  public.tblcast VALUES ('Henry Cavil', :LASTOID)" | psql yourdb
```

**lo_export**:

```
psql yourdb -c "SELECT lo_export(castimage, 'path_to_export_file') FROM tblcast;"
```

**pg_read_file** (less flexible):

This [`generic file access function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-admin.html) offers the possibility to read files in the server. However, it is limited to the data directory path. If you want to know where it is in your system, try the following command:

```
SHOW data_directory
```

And here would be a way of how to use it - as also shown in the answer from Mike Pur:

```
INSERT INTO public.tblcast(castname, castimage)
VALUES ('Henry Cavill',pg_read_file('path to file')::bytea);
```

Comment: That worked. it is now showing binary data in the corresponding field.

Answer (score 2):

Use pg_read_file

```
INSERT INTO public.tblcast(
    castname, castimage)
    VALUES ('Henry Cavill',pg_read_file('E:\Cast\henry.jpg')::bytea);
```

Comment: `invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff` this error is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lo_import('E:\Cast\henry.jpg')` instead of `bytea('E:\Cast\henry.jpg')`

Comment: `You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.` i used bytea while creating the table. any chance i can insert without changing the data type?